# Spring security Access Denied event with proper role

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Good day everyone.

I got a spring mvc application with spring security layer.
So i configured security to permit access for /good-transfer/** URL for all users who has one of four roles

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                // For all static resources we got permissions
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**","/font/**").permitAll()
                // Good transfer
                .antMatchers("/good_transfer/**").hasAnyRole(UserRole.ROLE_ASSEMBLER.name(),UserRole.ROLE_LOADER.name(),UserRole.ROLE_SHIPPER.name(),UserRole.ROLE_SELLER.name())
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and();

        http.formLogin()
                // указываем страницу с формой логина
                .loginPage("/login")
                // указываем action с формы логина
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                // указываем URL при неудачном логине
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                // Указываем параметры логина и пароля с формы логина
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                // даем доступ к форме логина всем
                .permitAll();

        http.logout()
                // разрешаем делать логаут всем
                .permitAll()
                // указываем URL логаута
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                // указываем URL при удачном логауте
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                // делаем не валидной текущую сессию
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }
```

I submit login form with login and password of user with role ROLE_ASSEMBLER and after a successful login i fall to / controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController extends CommonController
{
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login()
    {
        return model("login");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView main(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String redirect = "login";

        if(request.isUserInRole(UserRole.ROLE_ASSEMBLER.name())||request.isUserInRole(UserRole.ROLE_LOADER.name())||request.isUserInRole(UserRole.ROLE_SHIPPER.name())||request.isUserInRole(UserRole.ROLE_SELLER.name()))
        {
            redirect = "good_transfer";
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/"+redirect);
    }

}
```

The expression request.isUserInRole(UserRole.ROLE_ASSEMBLER.name()) returns true, so i got a role needed. After that controller redirects me to /good-transfer URL (i got a controller for that URL):

```
@Controller
public class GoodTransferController extends CommonController
{
    @RequestMapping("/good_transfer")
    public ModelAndView getAssemblyList()
    {
        ModelAndView model = model("good-transfer");
        return model;
    }
}
```

But i can`t each the controller`s method :(.
It throws the AccessDenied exception...

I can`t understand why. This URL must be permitted for ROLE_ASSEMBLER users.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it work.

My security configuration wanted user roles without "ROLE_" prefix.

Changed it to:

```
http.csrf()
                .disable()
                // For all static resources we got permissions
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**","/font/**").permitAll()
                // Good transfer
                .antMatchers("/good_transfer/**").hasAnyRole(UserRole.ROLE_ASSEMBLER.role(),UserRole.ROLE_LOADER.role(),UserRole.ROLE_SHIPPER.role(),UserRole.ROLE_SELLER.role())
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and();
```

And it started to work!